# Is it possible to create video alarm in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

I need to create a video alarm in IPhone app. Is it possible to create such app ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with a "video alarm"? How is it supposed to work? etc. Please explain so that people can understand

Comment: Like in other alarms, a sound plays unless you tap snooze or turn it off. In similar way I need a way to play a video instead of sound.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to play a video on a given time, it's only possible while the app is open and active.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EventKit FrameWork` for getting alarm alert and set time date month year and your event desciprtion!  When event Started Load your forground Movie using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: It won't be possible to launch the app without the user's interaction following the local notification.